# Importing mahout 0.11 version in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mahout, mahout-recommender

How can I import [Mahout 0.11.0](http://www.us.apache.org/dist/mahout/0.11.0/) version on Eclipse ? I couldn't find any jar file in the download file.

Comment: What file did you download exactly? How do you want to import mahout in eclipse? There is too less information.